# Change body class from a drop down list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do you change the body class from a drop down list using jQuery?

Comment: have you tried anything? it's that simple as getting the value of the selected option and assigning it to body.. You should try to do it yourself

Comment: Please state the work you have already done so far. If you haven't done any, please refer the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: please add more info to your question.  Perhaps some code and the things youve tried etc...

Comment: I have already tried to do it. But it now works with links and not drop down lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // On load

  $('#MyDropDownId').change(function(){ // on change event
    $('body')
    .removeClass() // remove the classes on the body
     // or removeClass('class1 class2 ...') in order to not affect others classes
    .addClass( $(this).val() ); // set the new class
  })

})
```

**Assuming :**

```
<select id="MyDropDownId">
  <option value="class1">First Class</option>
  <option value="class2">2nd Class</option>
</select>
```

Read more on [JQuery Change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Why not simply `.attr('class', $(this).val())`? (On the assumption only *one* class-name should ever be applied.)

Comment: @DavidThomas Good Idea, but I tried to describe the functionality of the JQuery functions (since I felt that the OP has no knowledge on jQuery), maybe he want only to remove a set of defined classes only e.g.`removeClass('class1 class2 class3')` and not to affect others classes on the body

Comment: :) I do have a little knowledge in jQuery. The intention it to remove certain classes and then to put other based on the drop down list in place. I think however I could use the code supplied to make sure it works as it should.

Comment: I found this solution the most versatile, it works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').change(function() {
     $('body').addClass($(this).val());
});
```

If you google "jQuery input change" you will find the `.change()` method. If you google for "jQuery change class" you will come across multiple methods that allow you to add, remove and modify classes.

Add a bit of creativity and *whoosh* you magically invented something far beyond Einstein's capabilities.

Google is a developers' most valuable tool. With great power comes great responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to `change the body class on change event of dropdown`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LxkY3/2/)**

```
<select id="dropdownId" >
  <option>class1</option>
  <option>class2</option>
  <option>class3</option>    
</select>

$('#dropdownId').change(function() {
    $('body').attr('class', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I will award the best answer by the end of today. Thank you guys ever so much. I know a little jQuery, but I have not had an opportunity to use custom jQuery on projects yet.